# Gradle: Resolved versions for app and test app differ

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-testing

When I add the dependency:

```
compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android:0.7.8'
```

in my app, I get this error:

```
Conflict with dependency 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy'. Resolved versions for app (0.7.8) and test app (0.6.14) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

I have visited http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict and it says:

> Gradle build will fail if the main APK and the test APK use the same
>   library (e.g. Guava) but in different versions.[...] To make the build
>   succeed, just make sure both APKs use the same version

But I don't know what it means.

Can you help me? Thanks.

**build.gradle**

```
    ...
     buildTypes {

            all {
                //just build some config fields
            }

            demo.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
            demo {
                //just build some config fields
            }

            devel.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
            devel {
                //just build some config fields
            }

            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.gg
                //just build some config fields
            }
        }

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}

    ...
```

Comment: show your gradle files

Comment: Which part? `build.gradle` is very large...

Comment: the one that refers to the byte-buddy-android and maybe your build flavours?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force the version in your test using:

```
androidTestCompile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android:0.7.8'
```

Comment: It works. But now I just can use it in test classes, since it is a test dependency. What can I do?

Comment: @bigdestroyer You have to use androidTestCompile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android:0.7.8' and compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android:0.7.8' together in your build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

You can force the version without adding an extraneous dependency by adding this to your gradle file

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android:0.7.8'
    }
}
```