# Android Conflict with dependency appcompat

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-espresso

I am trying to add the espresso-contrib library to my project. Here is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com.littlebox_hari"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    /*configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        }
    }*/
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
}
```

I get this error :

```
Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'. Resolved versions for app (23.4.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

If I uncomment the lines in my build.gradle file, I get :

```
Error:(72) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1'.
Error:(75) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
Error:(79) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
Error:(76) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
Error:(82) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
Error:(89) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button'.
D:\Littlebox-Hari\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\design\23.1.1\res\values\values.xml
Error:(97, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAllCaps'.
Error:(102, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
Error:(113, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundTint'.
Error:(113, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
Error:(122, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
Error:(131, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
```

Edit : I added the following line to my build.gradle file :

```
testCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you read the URL the error provided?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle: Resolved versions for app and test app differ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650509/gradle-resolved-versions-for-app-and-test-app-differ)

Comment: Edited - I got the same error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I also faced this issue today.

First, update the dependencies to their latest versions (0.5 and 2.2.2).

See: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/downloads/

```
// Android JUnit Runner
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'

// JUnit4 Rules
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'

// Espresso core
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'

// Espresso-contrib for DatePicker, RecyclerView, Drawer actions, Accessibility checks, CountingIdlingResource
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'

// Espresso-web for WebView support
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'

// Espresso-idling-resource for synchronization with background jobs
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2'
```

Then, you'll face the same error, since the latest version isn't still using the latest version of the support library as of now (23.4.0). There's an issue open on the bug tracker already: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211490

This worked for me:

```
dependencies {
    ext {
        supportLibVersion = '23.4.0'
        espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile ("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espressoVersion") {
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude module: 'design'
    }
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:$espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
}
```

**EDIT:**
According to this codepath [guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html), it seems like this is the correct way:

```
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '24.1.1'
    espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    mockitoVersion = '1.10.19'
    hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
    powerMockitoVersion = '1.6.5'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"

    // Testing dependencies
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:$mockitoVersion"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$hamcrestVersion"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:$powerMockitoVersion"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:$powerMockitoVersion"
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:$espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$espressoVersion"
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibVersion"
}

configurations.compile.dependencies.each { compileDependency ->
    println "Excluding compile dependency: ${compileDependency.getName()}"
    configurations.androidTestCompile.dependencies.each { androidTestCompileDependency ->
    configurations.androidTestCompile.exclude module: "${compileDependency.getName()}"
}
```

Comment: I also had to add this one line in the espresso-contrib excludes: exclude module: 'support-v4'

Answer (score 0):

These two configs worked for me after hacking around with tons of other build.gradle files ( reading too many android books where the gradle settings have changed, merging with hacked gradle files from countles swebsites , merged with gradle files from google's own recommended gradle files that were still obsolete )   because frankly Gradle and it's build system sucks ( completely inferior to CMake/Rake/Scons/Make ).

/* main buid.gradle */

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "com.github.tkruse.groovysh" version "1.0.8" // optional
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// Define versions in a single place
ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 10
    targetSdkVersion = 22
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = '23.0.3'

    // App dependencies
    supportLibraryVersion = '23.4.0'
    guavaVersion = '18.0'
    glideVersion = '3.6.1'
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    mockitoVersion = '1.10.19'
    powerMockito = '1.6.2'
    hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
    runnerVersion = '0.5'
    rulesVersion = '0.5'
    espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
}
```

and

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.testing.notes"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // Run code coverage reports by default on debug builds.
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }

    // If you need to add more flavors, consider using flavor dimensions.
    productFlavors {
        mock {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".mock"
        }
        prod {

        }
    }

    // Remove mockRelease as it's not needed.
    android.variantFilter { variant ->
        if(variant.buildType.name.equals('release')
                && variant.getFlavors().get(0).name.equals('mock')) {
            variant.setIgnore(true);
        }
    }

    // Always show the result of every unit test, even if it passes.
    testOptions.unitTests.all {
        testLogging {
            events 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'standardOut', 'standardError'
        }
    }

}

/*
 Dependency versions are defined in the top level build.gradle file. This helps keeping track of
 all versions in a single place. This improves readability and helps managing project complexity.
 */
dependencies {
    // App's dependencies, including test
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:$rootProject.guavaVersion"
    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$rootProject.glideVersion"
    compile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"

    // Dependencies for local unit tests
    testCompile "junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junitVersion"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$rootProject.ext.hamcrestVersion"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:$rootProject.ext.powerMockito"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:$rootProject.ext.powerMockito"

    // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:$rootProject.ext.runnerVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:$rootProject.ext.rulesVersion"

    // Espresso UI Testing dependencies.
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
}

/*
Resolves dependency versions across test and production APKs, specifically, transitive
dependencies. This is required since Espresso internally has a dependency on support-annotations.
*/
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
}

/*
All direct/transitive dependencies shared between your test and production APKs need to be
excluded from the test APK! This is necessary because both APKs will contain the same classes. Not
excluding these dependencies from your test configuration will result in an dex pre-verifier error
at runtime. More info in this tools bug: (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192497)
*/
configurations.compile.dependencies.each { compileDependency ->
    println "Excluding compile dependency: ${compileDependency.getName()}"
    configurations.androidTestCompile.dependencies.each { androidTestCompileDependency ->
        configurations.androidTestCompile.exclude module: "${compileDependency.getName()}"
    }
}
```